# JS DOM elements’ content-string properties: memory management and computation in current engines

Tags: string, performance, dom, memory-management, browser

In the DOM, the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) types have many dynamic properties, e.g., `Node.textContent` and `Element.innerHTML`, that return string representations of the nodes’ contents.

The DOM specifications state only that these methods are simply to “return” `DOMStrings`, i.e., `string`s. But they, of course, do not specify when and how these strings are allocated and computed. For text nodes, an implementation can clearly simply return its plain-text string content directly. But `Element`s must create new strings that contain the tags and contents of any descendant elements.

As far as I can tell, an implementation may allocate memory for these strings and compute their values at four points:

1. Immediately, when the `Element` is first created;
2. Lazily, scheduled sometime after the `Element`’s creation;
3. Lazily, on demand at the point when getting a string property from the `Element`;
4. Or lazily, on demand whenever the string is first used (i.e., the returned string uses a special, externally indistinguishable implementation that is immediately returned by the `Element`’s string properties but which dynamically generates its value when needed).

These methods would also determine when the strings’ memory is freed. The first two techniques essentially cache the string in the `Element` object—they create a reference to the string from the `Element`, and the string will not be deallocated until the `Element` is. The third and fourth techniques might but need not create such a reference from the `Element`; the string’s memory may be deallocated long before the `Element` is, as long as its other references are freed. In addition, an implementation might use two, three, or all of these possibilities based on some heuristic.

Which techniques do modern browser engines use? This question has clear performance ramifications, both in computation time and memory allocation, for any sort of DOM manipulation and text retrieval. But as far as I can tell these properties’ performance characteristics are unknown or not documented.

Comment: This kind of thing is generally done by [the layout engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Document_Object_Model)) rather than the [JavaScript engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine), so I'm not sure that the JavaScript tag is warranted.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The best other tag I could find was #browser, and I had difficulty deciding between it and #javascript. I picked the former since the DOM as of now, of course, implies JavaScript, #browser is even broader as a topic than #javascript, and I wanted to get the question in front of people tracking #javascript. But if you have a better alternative, I would be fine replacing #javascript with it.